# Why upperBounds and lowerBounds of WildcardType are array in java?

Tags: java, reflection, wildcard

Why upperBounds and lowerBounds of `WildcardType` are array in java?

```
// Only has a Number
? extends Number
```

`T` has two (`Number` and `Serializable`) but `T` is `TypeVariable` **not** `WildcardType`

```
T extends Number & Serializable
```

And in jdk implementation `com.sun.beans.WildcardTypeImpl` and `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl` I see this code in `toString()`:

```
for(int var3 = 0; var3 < var2.length; ++var3) {
            if (var3 > 0) {
                var1.append(" & ");
            }

            var1.append(var2[var3] instanceof Class ? ((Class)var2[var3]).getName() : var2[var3].toString());
        }
```

Why? Is this legal??? `? extends Number & Serializable`

Same problem for `rawType` of `ParameterizedType`: Why return `Type` **not** `Class`?

Comment: "? extends Number & Serializable" is legal, yes.

Comment: *What*? Do you mean the `&` syntax for lower and upper bounds?

Comment: @LouisWasserman sure? which version? could you show me an example？

Comment: @user207421 yes

Comment: @FredSuvn, here is the relevant _Java Tutorial_.  I believe this synatx was added after the initial release of _Generics_, although I'm not sure.  _[Bounded Type Parameters (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Generics (Updated))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)_.

Answer (score 4):

I think it’s valid to say that this part of the Reflection API is not a good API at all. The base type [`java.lang.reflect.Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) does not provide any helpful query methods, except for the name and even that was added as late as Java 8.

So from Java 5 to Java 7, developers were left with an empty interface. And even today, it requires a bunch of `instanceof` tests to find out what you are looking at. This is, of course, especially awful if it’s not clear what possibilities exist, in other words, what you have to test for.

The case of `getRawType()` declaring the base type `Type` when it is always expected to be a `Class` (or is it?), is bad. But the case of the bounds is even weirder.

The question whether a wildcard type can have multiple upper bounds is actually independent from the question whether the method `getUpperBounds()` can ever return an array with more than one element.

In general, wildcard types with multiple bounds are possible, but only as a result of type inference. At a first glance, this applies to intermediate values only, whose types are never reported by Reflection and so the designers of Generics did not consider this scenario when defining the bytecode format. In other words, *it’s impossible to describe a wildcard with multiple bounds in [the bytecode format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9.1)*.

Since the assumption that such inferred types can not occur as part of runtime Reflection visible artifacts was actually wrong, we can test it:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Tmp<T> {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    withTypeVariable(null);
    withWildcardType();
  }

  public static <T extends Number & Serializable> void withTypeVariable(T t) {
    var tmp = new Tmp<T>(t, t);

    Serializable s = tmp.get();
    Number n = tmp.get();

    tmp.new Inner() { { printType(getClass().getGenericSuperclass()); } };
  }

  public static void withWildcardType() {
    var tmp = new Tmp<>(10, 1.0);

    Serializable s = tmp.get();
    Number n = tmp.get();

    tmp.new Inner() { { printType(getClass().getGenericSuperclass()); } };
  }

  Tmp(T t1, T t2) {}

  T get() {
    return null;
  }

  class Inner {}

  static void printType(Type type) {
    System.out.println(type);
    Type typeArg = ((ParameterizedType)
        ((ParameterizedType)type).getOwnerType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    Type[] bounds;
    if(typeArg instanceof TypeVariable<?> tv) {
      System.out.print(tv.getName());
      bounds = tv.getBounds();
    }
    else if(typeArg instanceof WildcardType wt) {
      System.out.print("?");
      bounds = wt.getUpperBounds();
    }
    else {
      System.out.println(typeArg);
      return;
    }
    String s = " extends ";
    for(var b: bounds) {
      System.out.print(s + b);
      s = " & ";
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

This shows two similar scenarios with a type with upper bounds, once a type variable and once a wildcard type. The `get()` calls demonstrate the presence of both bounds, `Number` and `Serializable`, in either case.

As said above, the wildcard case isn’t expressible in bytecode. So what happens? Recent `javac` versions simply refuse to compile this code, because they can’t generate a valid signature attribute. Recent eclipse versions use a work-around. With this work-around, the compiled program prints

```java
Tmp<T>$Inner
T extends class java.lang.Number & interface java.io.Serializable
Tmp<java.lang.Number>$Inner
class java.lang.Number
```

So the inexpressible `? extends Number & Serializable` became just `Number` despite the `get()` calls pass, demonstrating that the code actually uses `? extends Number & Serializable`.

Note that both behaviors are an improvement to earlier versions, as in the past, both compilers generated illegal signatures in such scenarios which would fail at runtime. Compare with bug reports [ECJ 494198](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494198) and [JDK-8016196](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8016196).

Further note that you don’t need `var` for this issue. I only used it here so I can add the `get()` calls. A code construct like `new Tmp<>(10, 1.0).new Inner() { … }` would run into this issue in all Java versions with Generics.

So, while wildcard types with multiple bounds are possible, you will never get an array with more than one element from `getUpperBounds()` or `getLowerBounds()`—at least if the interface implementation truly reflects what has been found in an actual class file. And, as far as I know, there are no scenarios with multiple lower bounds.

I notice that this answer didn’t explain *why* these methods were defined to return an array. But we probably will never know. At least, I tried to provide all information there is about it.

Comment: What a wild read this was. Thank you for such a detailed explanation!